# Does Selenium delete cookies?

Tags: python, django, selenium, cookies

In order to make functional tests cleaner, I am using a pre-authenticated session so that I can skip login for each use case that requires it. 
Using Selenium, I visit the website and set the cookie.

```
def create_pre_authenticated_session(self, email):
    user = User.objects.create_user(email=email, password="pass")

    session = SessionStore()
    session[SESSION_KEY] = user.pk
    session[BACKEND_SESSION_KEY] = settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS[1]
    session.save()

    ## to set a cookie we need to first visit the domain.
    ## 404 pages load the quickest!
    self.browser.get(self.live_server_url + "/404_no_such_url/")
    self.browser.add_cookie(dict(
        name=settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME,
        value=session.session_key,
        path='/',
))
```

The problem is that, after running the function shown above (and I confirm that the cookie was set in the browser), I visit the address relevant for my test and the cookie is gone.

If I do this use case manually against the django dev server, all works well ie. I can skip login and go straight to the relevant page.
Selenium version is 2.45

Any ideas of what's going on here ?

Comment: Please show the code above together with the test class that uses it so that we can see how it is called. Narrowing it down to the smallest test case that reproduces the behavior would be helpful.

Comment: @Louis, I found your comment now that I came back to share what I've found. Basically, I wasn't setting session[HASH_SESSION_KEY] = user.get_session_auth_hash(). The example I followed was not meant for user/pass authentication and therefore HASH_SESSION_KEY wasn't needed. In my particular case, it is.

Comment: Hmm... I do what you are trying to do without having to set `HASH_SESSION_KEY` manually.

Comment: how do you do it then ?

Comment: `user = authenticate(username=username, password=password); s = SessionStore(); s[SESSION_KEY] = user.pk; s[BACKEND_SESSION_KEY] = user.backend; s.save()`. The `authenticate` function is from `django.contrib.auth`.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it's definitely cleaner than setting HASH_SESSION_KEY manually.

Comment: Do you mean to say you tried what I put in the comment and it worked for you?

Comment: from reading your code, it seemed more elegant than my solution. But now after trying it out, it actually does not work for me

Comment: I would have been surprised if my code had solved your problem. So, going back to `HASH_SESSION_KEY` if setting it solves your problem, and you want to self-answer, then I would suggest explaining *why* it solves the problem. Otherwise, people won't know whether your problem mirrors their own situation. (It does not mirror mine, for instance, seeing as I don't need to set `HASH_SESSION_KEY`.)